# How to create a Custom Function with an loops inside of javascript on google apps script and implent it to spreadsheet of "C2:C" of range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

**I use a google apps script to make a function which when I call it into spreadsheet cells as a custom function** but it's seems looks like won't to looping one of them or anything. Which is when I call the custom function like this "**=setSheetIdhere()**" the output come just give me something or came out with something result like of the single cell data of the result only that the value is "**0**".

```
function setSheetIdhere() {
  for (var i=0; i < sss.length; i++) {
    return [[sss[i].getSheetId()]];
  }
}
```

***Here I attached a pic to describbing more my Explaination.*** *The Problem is How to generate or collecting or set all Ids of the All Sheets ???*

[image]

Comment: What is `sss`?  It's not defined in your function.  It must be an array of sheets, but where is it defined?  Do you realize that your loop is only going to run once because of the return?

Comment: Your comment `Just shows the value zero only` is because on a new spreadsheet the sheetId for the first sheet is always zero.  And since your loop always stops during the first iteration you always get zero.  I think you need to rethink that a little.

Comment: Custom functions are treated as deterministic - they are explicitly assumed to ALWAYS return the same value for the same input. If you write a custom function that is not deterministic, that is **your error**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran this on a newly created spreadsheet:

```
function spreadsheetIds() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets().map(function(sh){return sh.getSheetId();});
  Logger.log(shts);
  //output - [0, 1550400053, 206842422, 247142844, 124067339]

}

function testsetSheetsId() {
  Logger.log(setSheetsId());
  //always returns zero
}
```

This is essentially what your function must be I think.  If you run  testsetSheetsId() you'll find that it always returns zero.

```
function setSheetsId() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for (var i=0; i <shts.length ; i++) {
    return shts[i].getSheetId();
  }
}
```

I think you just need to run a function like this one time and you're done.

```
function generateSheetIdsIntoAColumn(startrow,startcolumn) {
  var startcolumn=startcolumn||3;
  var startrow=startrow||2;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var sA=[];
  shts.forEach(function(s){sA.push([s.getSheetId()]);});  
  var rg=sh.getRange(startrow,startcolumn,sA.length,sA[0].length).setValues(sA);
}
```

But this is not a cell function.

I played around with this a bit and I found that you can run it with an installable onChange() trigger and it will update the list every time you add another sheet.

This is the code:

```
//This is modified to run with the event object instead of parameters for controlling where the column starts
function generateSheetIdsIntoAColumn(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if(e.changeType=='INSERT_GRID') {    
    var startcolumn=3;
    var startrow=2;
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var shts=ss.getSheets();
    var sA=[];
    shts.forEach(function(s){sA.push([s.getSheetId()]);});  
    sh.getRange(startrow,startcolumn,sA.length,sA[0].length).setValues(sA);
  }
}

//This installs the onChange event trigger
function installonChange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(!isTrigger('generateSheetIdsIntoAColumn')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('generateSheetIdsIntoAColumn').forSpreadsheet(ss).onChange().create();
  }
}

//this functions helps you to keep from creating more than one trigger
function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Unfortunately, onChange() trigger doesn't happen when a script inserts a sheet.  It only works when user adds a sheet.  Sorry, I guess I can't help you much here to get it done automatically without polling with a time based trigger.

Comment: _**@Cooper**_ I think You are a good one of the best ...  You did it ! Cooper. what I wish has done by you. Thank you so much Cooper. At the rest let me handle it consendering with my circumstances here but what have been the important is this is really the most almost closest I think really I should have to say so so thanksfull for you ...   #sorry for my poor english ;p